# connectivity issue: 0 mbit upload on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking

I four devices available to me: an android phone, two laptops (DELL and Lenovo) running Ubuntu 16.04 (upgraded from 14 LTS) and a very similar Lenovo running Windows. Since I had very strange connectivity issues with google services on both Ubuntu machines at a very specific wifi I did some checking:

Using `speedtest.net` from the browser I checked the speeds reported by the Windows machine: around 30-40 ms pings, and around 40/8 Mbit/s down/up speeds. The `speedtest.net` app reports very similar measurements on the android device. On the Lenovo Ubuntu using `speedtest-cli` from the terminal and `speedtest.net` from a browser both report around the same speeds 15-20 ms pings, 25-30 Mbit/s download and 90% of the time 0.00 upload speeds (very rarely I actually measure 1.6 or something it is very transient). Interestingly the DELL Ubuntu machine reports pretty normal upload speeds but Firefox still can't load google services properly (Chrome can, on the Lenovo Ubuntu neither Chrome nor Firefox can, but of course with zero upload speed that is not so suprising).

Once I tried using a cable instead of wifi, and I think it didn't help, but I have no cables around now to double check. But all devices have worked for me with every other wifi I have come into contact with so far, so there is something very strange going on here.

I don't really know what could be the problem at all, so I am hoping you have some good ideas where to look around.

**Update:** the wifi connection details

```
$ iwlist wlan0 s
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 44:32:C8:34:8F:16
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"UPC1127202"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000014eca05fb9
                    Extra: Last beacon: 72776ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000A55504331313237323032
                    IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 0706444520010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 200100
                    IE: Unknown: 23021200
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0504002A0000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A3C191BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080400080000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180204000C0000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101880003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 46057208010000
```

**Update 2:**

The issue is definitely NOT the wireless connection itself. Using a mobilephone to connect to the wifi and than sharing the connection via a usb tether to the computer, the computer still gets 0 Mbit/s upload while the phone can do 9 Mbit/s (measured via speedtest).

Comment: It seems the issue occur only in a specific network and only with Ubuntu machines, is it correct? If so then there's something different in that network. Without other info no-one can know for sure but I can hypothesize the culprit are bad wireless encryption settings, either a WPA/WPA2 mixed mode, TKIP or both (the worse case scenario). The recommend (and only) settings thst should be used are WP2-AES. Unfortunately the not-recommended-at-all settings seems to be the default in many ISP installed routers.

Comment: Ans yes, Windows and others may work acceptably even with the bad settings. Certain devices with some Linux drivers are the ones that don't like those settings. The same devices in Windows may work fine. But all will work better and safer if you always use the recommended settings above.

Comment: It seems you might be right in guessing the encryption, but if Windows can handle this, home come mighty Linux cannot? :D I mean there should be a solution, right?

Comment: As a matter of fact *nothing* should be OK with it. TKIP has been deprecated in the 802.11 standard for years and no-one uses WPA for more than a decade. Being lax/permissive in this context is **not** a good thing. So, IMO there shouldn't be a "solution" and whatever passes for that would have to be dealt at drivers (and hardware) level, nothing directly related with Ubuntu (the OS), let alone Linux (the kernel).

Comment: I checked and ruled out the wireless connection being bad. I am suspecting that the ISP has something very messed up.

Comment: After a call to the ISP (unfortunately not by me, so the answer is a bit vague), it had something to do with IPv6 being enabled - I guess - on the router/modem. Confounds me why that would give me 0 upload, but anyway, it works now.